# how to add extension in php Opensuse

Tags: php, linux

I want to add an extension so I can use my own function in php for example my codes of C  but I don't know the requisites and instructions of doing it.I have php5 and OS:Opensuse 11. 
I don't know about configure and the codes in shell
there should be something like ext_skel so I can create config files but I don't have it should I download it from somewhere?

Due to this link http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/20/3/0
there should be ext directory but I don't have it.

Thanks in Advance

```
cd 
vi ext/util/config.m4a
./build conf --force
./configure => i don't know here
```

Comment: You are aware you don't need to build a PHP extension in order to [define functions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)? Extensions are *hard*

Comment: suppose we have my own function foo() I want it to be in php functions then I can use this like for example echo function of php then no need to write it

Comment: that is usually solved by having library PHP files and importing them into the current script using `include()`. A rule of thumb for writing PHP extensions is: if you don't know how to do it, you probably shouldn't be doing it. Extensions need knowledge in C and the underlying concepts of PHP. They need to be compiled and installed.

Comment: my extensions are here /usr/lib/php5/extensions I cope pasted my own file there now my problem is that how to config and handle it

Comment: what kind of file did you paste there? A compiled extension?

Comment: for example implementation of echo is not in php maybe it's another format

Comment: What kind of file did you paste in the extensions directory? What does it contain?

Comment: @Pekka the formats are .c and .h

Comment: have you followed the instructions how to write a PHP extension? They should also cover installing it, shouldn't they?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: [PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide to the Zend Engine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) and maybe [PHP: Extension structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php)

Comment: Yes I am updating the code of config in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download PHP and then change to the ext directory and follow the tutorial. Don't forget to compile PHP too, because the extension you create depends heavily on the PHP version. I've installed OpenSuse but I don't think it does affect building a PHP extension. You might need some compiler tools etc. I found /php-5.2.6/ext/ext_skel in my PHP path. I've PHP installed in my home directory. You need to install the sources. In OS it's zypper in php5-devel. You can also download the tarball from the PHP site.

Edit: Here is another tutorial about php extension programming.

Comment: where is ext directory? I have extension directory but not ext

Comment: Did you look into all the PHP directory? Use find . -name "*ext*". Or look for the script ext_skel with the same comand.

Comment: I did these things but I don't have it i am sure that i don't have it.

Comment: I just have this /usr/lib/php5/extensions

Comment: That doesn't look like the PHP code. Normaly OpenSuse doesn't install the header files. You need the install them with zypper or download the tarball from the PHP site.

Comment: but I run my php pages very easily i have apache and mysql and php5

Comment: That doesn't matter if you want to build your own extension you need the PHP code. I've lighttpd it's much better then apache.

Comment: Jitamaro I have php5 ok? now tell me what should i exactly do? uninstall it and download it from php.net? then i have ext directory? would you please tell me path of your ext directory?

Comment: @nik parase: Learn the fundamentals of programming: Source-code, compiling and binaries. Then learn how that works with your operating system, then learn how that works with PHP on your operating system. http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Compile_Software_from_Source_Code

Comment: @nik: If you want help then you need to be nice. If you want to make rules go away.

Comment: in the manual of /usr/share/doc/packages/php5/README.EXT_SKEL it tells that it is from php4! WEIRD

Comment: what do you mean making rules?! what sentence of me was bad? I just wanted help!

Comment: I even told that I will uninstall php5! what should i do to not assuming it a rule! OMG!

Comment: @nik: I found /php-5.2.6/ext/ext_skel in my PHP path.

Comment: thanks jitamaro I have this:/usr/include/php5/ext now i should try yours

Comment: PHP 5.2.6 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Dec  3 2008 11:06:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
 my version is the same as you! what is before the address of the path that you entered?:"( :"( :"(

Comment: It's not a discussion forum and also I suggest you to ask another question because it is not clear to me what you want. I've PHP installed in my home directory. You need to install the sources. In OS it's zypper in php5-devel. You can also download the tarball from the PHP site.

Comment: can i talk to you?  nickparsa@gmail.com